# Best Practices for JWT Management in a Multi-Tenant System with User-Tenant Flexibility?

Tags: database, postgresql, security, jwt, row-level-security

I'm working on a multi-tenant system, and I am utilizing JWTs for user authentication and authorization. We add a tenant_id column to all tables for this purpose.
like this

```sql
CREATE POLICY tenant_isolation_policy ON tenant_business
USING (tenant_id = current_setting('app.current_tenant')::UUID);
```

My concerns are as follow:

If a user is removed from a tenant (especially by a tenant's admin), they could potentially continue performing operations under that tenant until the JWT expires. How can I mitigate this risk and ensure that evicted users lose access immediately?

I am confused as to whether I am overly concerned because many of the commentaries on RLS in multi-tenant system have no opinion on this. If this is an excessive concern, I'd like to know why it's excessive.

I'm looking forward to the community's insights on these challenges. Your experiences and recommendations will be immensely beneficial to me!

Comment: You have too many questions in one, please make the question more focused.

Comment: thanks @ErmiyaEskandary ! I've narrowed it down to one question and the questions that stem from it.

Comment: Thanks! Your concern is not excessive. Can you share what format your JWT is (reference vs self contained) and how you’re keeping track of them? Is your application the producer or are you using an external identity provider like Okta or Microsoft AD? Do you really need immediate revocation or is something like revocation within a time frame like 5 minutes viable?

Comment: I am using next-auth for jwt authentication. Thus my app is the producer and jwt is a self-contained format.
The expiration is 1 month (editable in 1s increments), and each time a session is started, it is rebuilt with a new 1 month.
It is often not a problem even after 5 minutes because the data is basic to browse. I just feel that it is a matter of the data actually being updatable, so I feel that an immediate expiration would be secure and preferable (this is the part where I said I was overly concerned).

Comment: Revoke the token on logout and keep a Redis or inmemory cache of 1 month for revoked tokens to make sure they're not used within the month that they could still be used as active.